# GWT ChildWindow.onClose?

Tags: gwt

In Javascript, I can do the following:

var child = window.open(URL, "_blank");
child.onclose = myChildCloseHandler();

Is it possible to do that same thing with GWT? The main problem seems to be that Window.open does not return any handle to the child window.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it in GWT:

- use Elemental (`elemental.html.Window` with `addEventListener`)
- use JSNI:

  ```java
  public native void open(String url) /*-{
    var child = window.open(url, "_blank");
    var that = this;
    child.onclose = $entry(function() {
      that.@com.example.client.MyClass::myChildCloseHandler()();
    });
  }-*/;
  ```

See also: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7822